# Discard branch in forked repo and make a copy of same branch from upstream into fork

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a forked repo with branch `develop`. When I make changes I usually pull from the upstream `develop` in to my forked branch and continue. Now I made a series of commits in my forked repo that I don't want to merge. So

1. How can reset my branch to be what the upstream branch is - like a sync
   or
2. How can I discard my branch and make a new copy of the upstream `develop` branch in my forked repo?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Since branches have virtually no cost in git you might want to create a backup branch before doing the reset (e.g. `git branch develop.old.backup develop`). You can always just delete it later if you want to)

The answer to 1) is a hard reset: `git checkout develop; git reset --hard origin/develop` (assuming the upstream repository is named *origin*). NB, the hard reset is a command that discards data and commits, which is what you ask for in this particular case, but it should be handled with respect<sup>1</sup>.

Alternative 2) would be

```bash
git checkout main  # or any other branch/commitish
git branch -D develop
git checkout -b develop origin/develop
```

---

<sup>1</sup>
I remember reading a humorous piece titled something "How to remove files as root in just 15 step" or something like that with exaggerated double/tripple checking of file masks and conditions before running an `rm` command as root. I was unable to find it now when searching for it.